# Alternative update technique using cx_Oracle to improve performance

Tags: python, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I have two lists of 100 elements each and a table that needs to be updated.

- list-A contains rowid records of a table-T.
- list-B contains values that need to be updated in table-T.

right now i have a query that loops over list-A by its rowid and updates a particluar field with value taken from list-B, if the rowid matches. The query looks like this :

```
"""update tableA set DKEY = :keyid    where ROWID = :rid""",
{"keyid":str(uid), "rid":str(rowid)}
```

the problem is this query is a slow. Probably because i have to loop over 100 elements. So i wonder if there's a batch update technique out there that i could use to improve the query's performance.

My setup : Python 2.7.5, cx_Oracle 5.1, oracle 11g

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do a batch insert into an Oracle database using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904033/how-can-i-do-a-batch-insert-into-an-oracle-database-using-python)

Comment: ahh yes, i have read that post. But it does not work with update statement.

Comment: Could you be a lot more specific please? `.executemany()` certainly works with UPDATE...