# SQL - Update all records of a single column

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to write a python script that parses through a file and updates a database with the new values obtained from the parsed file. My code looks like this:

```
startTime = datetime.now()

db = <Get DB Handle>

counter = 0

with open('CSV_FILE.csv') as csv_file:
    data = csv_file.read().splitlines()
    for line in data:
        data1 = line.split(',')
        execute_string = "update table1 set col1=" + data1[1] + 
                         " where col0 is '" + data1[0] + "'"
        db.execute(execute_string)
        counter = counter+1
        if(counter % 1000 == 0 and counter != 0):
            print ".",

print ""

print datetime.now() - startTime
```

But that operation took about 10 mins to finish. Any way I can tweak my SQL query to quicken it?

Comment: how big is your file? the speed problem could come from the " where col0 is '" + data1[0] + "'" line. As each time database has to find what to update. Alternative approach can be to import this file into the db first and do bulk update.

Comment: It should be faster to load the CSV file directly into a database table and then do the update based on the table.  In other words, do the hard lifting work in the DB rather than in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Read lines in batch size (may be size of 1000) and try bulk_update query for mysql. I think that process will be faster than current one as in lesser queries you'll be updating more data.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you need batching. Have a look at this question and best answer [How can I do a batch insert into an Oracle database using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904033/how-can-i-do-a-batch-insert-into-an-oracle-database-using-python)