# cx_Oracle error on access Json variable using Python

Tags: python, json, oracle, cx-oracle

I am new in Python and I am having throuble to get Json variable.

```
payload = ""
headers = {
    'Authorization': authorization,
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "65a104eb-1210-4eeb-880b-ceed78b21364"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

x = json.loads(response.text, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X',    
    d.keys())(*d.values()))

for a in x:
    print(a.numeroComlink)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('xxxxx/xxxxx@XE')
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql_insert = "insert into usu_obt_cot (usu_numclk) values (:usu_numclk)"
cursor.execute(sql_insert, {"usu_numclk": int(x.numeroComlink)})

connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

As you can see in the code above, I have a print on the middle of the code referencing the exact field that the error below says has no attribute.

[image: Error Received]

Since now I appreciate for attention.

Comment: This is a regular ole python error

Answer (score 0):

`Cursor.execute` will only execute a single insert statement, and x has many values in it. If you want it to insert all of the values in the `list` "x", you can either do a bunch of single insert statements in a loop (which is simple but probably won't perform terribly well)...

```
...
sql_insert = "insert into usu_obt_cot (usu_numclk) values (:usu_numclk)"
for a in x:
    cursor.execute(sql_insert, {"usu_numclk": int(a.numeroComlink)})
...
```

Or you could [follow the examples in this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904033/how-can-i-do-a-batch-insert-into-an-oracle-database-using-python) and try to do a batch insert with `Cursor.executeMany`.

Comment: I did what you suggested but I keep receiving the same error.

Comment: Do you still have anything saying `x.numeroComlink`? Because that's your problem. x is a list of objects with a `numeroComlink` attribute - but x doesn't have that attribute itself.