# Inserting multiple values in PL/SQL in Python with a single call

Tags: python, oracle, sql-insert, bulk

I need to insert multiple values in PL/SQL with a single call in Python because we have a 3Gb xml file.

Here is my code:

```
y = 0
for x in range(0,len(rows)):
    x = x + 1
    if x == y + 500 :
      cur.prepare("BULK INSERT INTO cm_raw (fecha,distname,clase,parametro,valor) VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)")
      datos = [(str(date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")),rows[y:x])]
      print (datos)
      cur.executemany(None,rows)
      con.commit()
      con.close
      y = x
```

[And this is  a screenshot of my error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGTuI.png)

Comment: `BULK INSERT ` is not available in oracle. maybe is just `insert` what you are looking for

Comment: yes, i try without BULK but not work. error is : cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type tuple not supported

Comment: We need insert many values because we have documents xml whit size 3gb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do a batch insert into an Oracle database using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904033/how-can-i-do-a-batch-insert-into-an-oracle-database-using-python)

Comment: No @KaushikNayak , because i have my code with the solution gave in the other problem and doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call PL/SQL with multiple data value look at the cx_Oracle examples [bind_insert.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/bind_insert.py), [batch_errors.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/batch_errors.py), and [array_dml_rowcounts.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/array_dml_rowcounts.py) from the cx_Oracle [samples directory](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/main/samples) which all insert multiple rows with one single `executemany()` call.

The examples show DML statements (INSERT etc) but you can also call a PL/SQL block multiple times with different parameters with `executemany()`:

```
data = [
    (10, 'Parent 10'),
    (20, 'Parent 20'),
    (30, 'Parent 30'),
    (40, 'Parent 40'),
    (50, 'Parent 50')
]
cursor.executemany("begin mypkg.create_parent(:1, :2); end;", data)
```

Using `executemany()` with SQL is going to be a *lot* faster than repeated calls to `execute()`.  It is also faster with PL/SQL unless you have OUT binds.

There is more information and more examples (including a PL/SQL one) on `executemany()` in [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html)

Comment: ROWS IS ROWS=""[[('07/06/2019', 'PLMN-PLMN', 'PLMN', '', '')],
 [('07/06/2019', 'PLMN-PLMN/OMC-103042', 'OMC', '$maintenanceRegionId', '2')],
  [('07/06/2019', 'PLMN-PLMN/BSC-224514','BSC', 'name', 'OMC')],
   [('07/06/2019', 'PLMN-PLMN/BSC-232892', 'BSC', '$maintenanceRegionId', '1400')],
    [('07/06/2019', 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-1807', 'MRBTS', 'wcdmaRanSaiPenalty', '127')],
     [('07/06/2019', 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-2115', 'MRBTS', 'sharedRfTechnologies', '0')]]

Comment: it's array list , no array

Comment: thanks, i could undestend an changed my array , thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for `INSERT ALL` instead of `BULK INSERT`. As hotfix mentioned, `BULK INSERT` is not available in Oracle. `INSERT ALL` is mentioned in Oracle's documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9015.htm#SQLRF01604

As for the `Python value of type tuple not supported` error you're receiving, please try reviewing this github thread. I am not familiar with Python but I think it may point you in the right direction: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/171

Comment: I could see and i change "bulk insert" for "insert all" and looking that https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/171 i can understend he problem but in he's problem he want insert many values and one array list, but i need insert many values, not many values with array list. Sry for my english