# Python ETL - Batch or Iteratively load Large datasets into Oracle Database with cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, dataframe, plsql, cx-oracle

Using Python to load a dataset of 10MM records into Oracle Database table. 
Dataframe created with no issue. When loading the dataframe record count too large error from cx_Oralce.

Seeking to loop over the dataframe and batch load the 10MM records by inserting hem 100k records at a time.

Code shwon below works, but only for small datasets that fit in allocated memory. I need one that works for batches and large datasets

Have tried iterating over rows, but this takes very long. Also have tried loading a much smaller data frame  - this works but does not achieve the goal.

Also tried using Bindarray and array size to lad the dataframe but nothing worked.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import sys
import re
from itertools import groupby, islice, takewhile
import cx_Oracle

format = '%y_%m_%d'

TODAY = datetime.date.today()
add = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = datetime.date.today() - add
dd = datetime.date.strftime(TODAY,format)

# connection variables
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user/Oracle_database_connect_info")
cur = connection.cursor()

# dataframe headers
columns = ['C1','C2','C3','C4']

# -- >> test and sample the file
csv_df = pd.read_csv(r'csvfile_location')

# add record_id for values
csv_df_idx = csv_df.index.values +1
csv_df.insert(0,column = 'RECORD_ID' , value=csv_df_idx)


### TABLE ALREADY CREATED IN DATABASE ###


for index, row in csv_df.iterrows():
    ### Insert and Iterate to inset records
    ### Convert to list for easy load into DB
    csv_df_dataset_lst = csv_df.values.tolist()
    insert_statement = """
    INSERT INTO TEST_LOAD
        ( RECORD_ID ,C1 ,C2 ,C3 ,C4)values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)    """

    # control number of records to bind for insert
    # cur.bindarraysize = 100000 # --->>> did not work
    # cur.arraysize = 100000 # --->>> did not work
    cur.executemany(insert_statement,csv_df_dataset_lst)
    connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Use Cursor.prepare() and Cursor.executemany(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904033/how-can-i-do-a-batch-insert-into-an-oracle-database-using-python

Comment: Can you please share the error message you get when this code executed for a large data set?

Comment: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1015: array size of 10000000 is too large

Comment: Figured it out.

Comment: Making a function in python that chunks the data frame  then iterates over this chunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The trick was to write a function that chunked the data frame into segments based on the size of the batches one wants to load.

Below is the final code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import sys
import re
from itertools import groupby, islice, takewhile
import cx_Oracle

format = '%y_%m_%d'

TODAY = datetime.date.today()
add = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = datetime.date.today() - add
dd = datetime.date.strftime(TODAY,format)

# connection variables
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user/Oracle_database_connect_info")
cur = connection.cursor()

# dataframe headers
columns = ['C1','C2','C3','C4']

# -- >> test and sample the file
csv_df = pd.read_csv(r'csvfile_location')

# add record_id for values
csv_df_idx = csv_df.index.values +1
csv_df.insert(0,column = 'RECORD_ID' , value=csv_df_idx)


### TABLE ALREADY CREATED IN DATABASE ###


# set batch size ie record count
batch_size = 100000

# create chunker function to separate the dataframe into batches
# Note: last batch will contain smallest amout of records.
def chunker(seq,size):
    return(seq[pos:pos+size] for pos in range(0,len(seq),size))


insert_statement = """
    INSERT INTO TEST_LOAD
        ( RECORD_ID ,C1 ,C2 ,C3 ,C4)values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)    """

# Optional use cursor.prepare so Oracle DB avoids compiling the insert statement over and over
try:
    cur.prepare(insert_statement)
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as Exception:
    printf('Failed to prepare insert cursor')
    printException(Exception)
    exit(1)

for i in chunker(csv_df,batch_size):
    ### Insert and Iterate to inset records
    ### Convert to list for easy load into DB
    csv_df_dataset_lst = csv_df.values.tolist()

    cur.executemany(insert_statement,csv_df_dataset_lst)
    connection.commit()
    # record counter to monitor the loading.
    number_of_records_loaded = cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*), SYSDATE FROM TEST_LOAD GROUP BY SYSDATE""")
    record_out = cur.fetchall()
    for row in record_out:
        print(row)
connection.close()
```

Comment: Since cx_Oracle uses statement caching, using an explict cursor.prepare may not help much.  Running a query to count records will just be overhead - why do you need it?  Why not use executemany()'s batchErrors mode?  If you know the data sizes, you can be more efficient by predefining memory.  You may want to take a look at the cx_Oracle documentation [Loading CSV Files into Oracle Database](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#loading-csv-files-into-oracle-database) - not that there is any single 'right' way to do this.